# Combine Bash associative arrays

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, associative-array

I am trying make a script that combines arrays on demand. Here is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -A code
code=( [H]="h" [E]="e" [L]="l" [P]="p" [M]="m" [E]="e" )
```

I need to print "help me" - without quotes and in one line - when I enter ./filename.bash "HELP ME" at command prompt.
here is what I am using.

```
code=$1;
for (( i = 0; i < ${#code[@]} ; i  = $i + 1 ));
do;
echo ${code[@]:$i:1};
done
```

Comment: Why are you overwriting your array with the positional parameter `$1`? you should be iterating over `$1`, using each of its characters to *index into* your `code` array, surely?

Comment: The idea here is to use $1 as a positional parameter. I have printed the code in simplest form. So, ./filename.bash "HELP ME" is $1 and code should print help me. In the same way, if I print ./filename.bash "PEEL" it should print peel in one line. Using [@] prints h e l p m e in different lines, even if I enter ./filename.bash "PEEL."

Comment: Why are you using arrays? it seems that the main thing you want to do is to invert the case of some text. You can do that very simply with `tr "a-zA-Z" "A-Za-z" <<<"HELP ME"` –   and, regarding associative arrays, you can use a space for the index `[' ']=' '` (if it helps).

Comment: Do you implement tr?: `tr "EHLMP" "ehlmp" <<< "HELP ME"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with `script.sh "HELP ME"`:

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1;
declare -A code
code=( [H]="h" [E]="e" [L]="l" [P]="p" [M]="m" [E]="e" )

for ((i=0; i<${#input}; i++))
do
  if [[ "${input:$i:1}" = " " ]]; then     # whitespace?
    echo -n " "
  else
    echo -n "${code[${input:$i:1}]}"
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
help me
```

Comment: Thank you! You are a life saver. The only other problem that I am now having is that when I add "please." after  echo -n "${code[${input:$i:1}]}" it prints out hpleaseepleaselpleasepplease and so on. Also echo -n prints behind the command prompt rather than after the command prompt.

Comment: If you want `help me please.` add as last additional line: `echo " please."`